# Cisco Data Center or Cisco UCS

Tags: cisco, vmware

I have heard that this new certification track, Cisco Data Center, is going to be the future, and Cisco UCS technology will replace traditional routers and switches.

How is the UCS different from traditional network systems?

I saw a blog in which there were posts that VMware NSX can be integrated with Cisco UCS to push the limits of these systems. Does using NSX mean that [vSphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_vSphere) runs on top of UCS, and NSX runs on top of vSphere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well,

This is a lot of questions and some misconceptions. Let me clarify few things.

First of all, Cisco DC certification track is like any other - has it's junior, senior and expert levels. Cisco UCS is on it's basic level an integrated computing system, and the Cisco Unified Fabric solution integrates computing (UCS), networking (Nexus) and application-awareness (ACI/APIC).

The idea for computing resources to fully replace routers & switches is promoted mostly by OpenFlow "believers", and while theoretically possible (look for definitions of SDN), it's currently feasible only to limited extent in software-defined environments, like fully integrated DC. You will see more and more physical boxes virtualized as software elements, but this has it's pros and cons, and there's no easy answer or direction.

As for NSX - it's networking virtualization solution, and can run on different hypervisors, doesn't have to be put on top of VMWare vSphere. And obviously, hypervisor needs an hardware to run on, so Cisco UCS can be the hardware. NSX is not the only solution for networking virtualization, or NfV (Networking functions Virtualization), it's just VMWare take at it.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco UCS is basically simply compute gear (memory, I/O, storage).

UCS will not replace Ethernet switches as there is always going to be a need for a box to physically plug the compute gear into.  Ethernet is not going away, even though they are trying to rename it to 'Fabric'.  Fabric is marketing, Ethernet is IEEE standard.

VMWare NSX is simply an overlay networking technology.  NSX traffic is tunneled across the underlying IP (layer3) network.  So is OTV, and many other fancy new acronyms.

The issue with Data Center being the future is at some point the rest of y'all are going to realize, ...wait a minute, why do I want to worry about all this, and you will purchase utility compute from a trusted mega compute player - Google, AWS, OpenShift online, Azure.

Learn software, how to create it, how to automate mundane tasks.  There's a future in Web development (lots of meat left on the Microsoft corpse).  Follow the mega vendors and most importantly the Standards bodies (IETF, ONF, W3C, etc).  You absolutely must become skilled in IP,JavaScript,HTML,CSS,and SQL + NoSQL databases.  I can't speak to Python as I have no interest in it at this time.

Comment: A brief answer to what I asked, following up with a good recommendation to progress if I love technology. Interestingly it so happened that I am into Automation now :)